# Developing "File Systems" for linux, mac, windows

Tags: filesystems

What technologies do applications such as dropbox (http://www.dropbox.com/) and expandrive (http://www.expandrive.com/mac) use to build functionality right into the local filesystems on each platform?  Can anyone suggest anything that would allow for maximum code reuse on all of the major platforms?

I've only looked into FUSE on linux so far and I like what I see.

Comment: The dropbox client doesn't actually implement a file system, it merely inspects and updates existing files. FUSE does something very different.

Comment: Generally, maximum code reuse is best achieved through well-thought architecture and generalization of the problem. And, as a matter of course, selection of a programming language / framework in case of multi-platform development.

Comment: In the dropbox case... In general how are they detecting a file has been modified?  I really don't want to get into specifics of their technology, but I am curious if they are simply doing something naive such as scanning files for the modified timestamp or something more sophisticated such as implementing some sort of notification/callback when a file is modified.  The latter case would be more interesting and I'd like to know if its even possible on any given platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implementing a virtual file system is very OS-specific. The reason is that architecture of drivers is different in Unix-like OS and in Windows.

To avoid writing your own driver, you can use user-mode file system toolkit. On Linux, BSD and MacOS there exist FUSE and OSXFUSE (fork of now-inactive MacFUSE) respectively. On Windows our [Callback File System](http://www.eldos.com/cbfs/) is used.

Dropbox at the moment doesn't have a virtual file system but only shell extension (afaik they planned to create a virtual disk but I don't know what they have decided).

Regarding how file changes are tracked: there exist several methods. The simplest is to scan the directory on timer and compare timestamps and file sizes. Next, one can use [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinAPI function. And the most sophisticated and most reliable method is to use a filesystem filter driver. On Windows our [CallbackFilter](http://www.eldos.com/cbflt/) can be used. On MacOS X and on Linux you can get post-notifications similar to what FileSystemWatcher offers in .NET/Windows. In particular, on Linux, one can use [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify).

Answer (score 4):

What you are after are usrspace filesystems. I don't know if there is a unified solution for implementing userspace filesystems on all (or most of all) platforms (probably not), but here's a starting point:

- for linux and (I think only some) unices: [fusefs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/)
- for windows: [dokan](http://dokan-dev.net/en/)
- for mac os: [macfuse](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/)

I am not familiar with all of them so I don't know how easy is to code proxies/interfaces so you can seamlessly implement filesystems in a platform-independent manner. Anyway, the operations that a filesystem is supposed to support are (to some extent) the same for everyone (open,read,write,etc) so at first sight this seems to be an easy start (even if coded with C preprocessing techniques, altho  you may want to take a look at C++ [boost](http://boost.org) libraries which are supposed to be highly platform independent and offer some good platform independent development tools as well).

Good luck!

Comment: In addition to FUSE, Dokan, CBFS, there is Pismo File Mount. PFM can be used to implement native file systems, in user mode, on Mac, Windows, and Linux. (Full disclosure: I am the primary PFM developer.)

Answer (score 1):

I've sort of encountering similar issues as yours: developing "cross-platform" file systems.

1. If you are going to develop a native file system, the best you can do is try to isolate as much as your file system algorithms (calculating disk-layout, checksums, directory data structures and etc.), besides the os-specific APIs, into ansi-c. You may read through ZFS code, which is considered well written so that it is relatively easy to port to FreeBSD/Mac/Linux.
2. Otherwise, if you can satisfy with the performance costs of user-land file systems, to maintain a file system across Mac/Linux/BSD is trivial. Using POSIX API, FUSE and 3rd-party libraries available on each platform, which is what I am doing now. However for windows, I've heard a FUSE implementation, but I don't think it is production-ready. So, as same as developing native file system, try to encapsulate your file system logics in ansi-c as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

it's quite easy on Windows to listen for file changes:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/atwhk15d(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: easy but not very reliable and with serious limitations.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example for a Mac OS FUSE implementation:
http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/23729/macfuse